# PHP date function does not print correct format

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

Can any one please help me to find out that what is wrong with following `date()` function format ??

```
$advised_time=date("D, d/n/Y", strtotime($this->input->post('advised_sign_on_date')));
```

The post variable `$this->input->post('advised_sign_on_date')` contains the date like : `"11-12-2014"`

when I print it shows the date format something like `Thu, 11V12V2014`. However, the format is fine but I do not understand why is `V` coming in instead of `/`.

**Update**

I figured out that this is happening because of `json_encode`. I was printing the `json_encode array` when I print the `$advised_time` it shows me correct format but I `json_encode` it escapes the slashes i guess. How can I avoid to do so ?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. It should be `Thu, 11/12/2014`

Comment: Cannot reproduce ~ https://eval.in/233264. You sure you're looking at the correct script?

Comment: Works fine for me.  What OS are you using?  Do you have any weird configurations in php.ini?

Comment: Wait, you wouldn't happen to be outputting this as JSON via `json_encode` would you? Look familiar ~ https://eval.in/233265?

Comment: how are you outputting or inspecting the variable? I suspect those are not `V`s but escaped slashes `\/`

Comment: Reading the JSON encoded string in JavaScript will remove the slash escaping. Example http://jsfiddle.net/d4fmudry/1/. Basically, you don't need to worry about it

Comment: json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); see: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

use default_timezone_set to set default timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('your time zone');
```

find your time zone on:
[click here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)